# Getting OutOfMemoryException in Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the value of
>   $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while executing
>   'java.exe'

I am getting out of memory exception in my visualstudio Xamarin Project Please help me how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: I would like to recommend not only to set LargeHeap to true. Instead you should try to figure out what is causing that OOM and fix that. Otherwise you might have bought you some time until it will hit you again.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

I would increase your build heap size.

Right click your Android Project > **Properties** > **Android Options** > **Advanced** > **Java Max Heap Size**.

[image]

Comment: Yes Your right. But where can i up my app size in visual studio xamarin.

Comment: @SrinivasCh In your manifest add the `android:largeHeap="true"`tag and then watch your `logcat` for `Grow heap (frag case)` to see when ART is trying to allocate more memory

Comment: Works well Thanks for reply @lain Smith

Comment: @SushiHangover Ah ok, I have had that error before and just upped the heap here, but you are right if you want your have to use a large heap then edit the manifes

Comment: @Srinivas-Ch no worries

Comment: @IainSmith, ahhh, need more coffee, I thought he was a app ART memory alloc failure, not a build error... cheers

Comment: for me other than 1G I had to also set build with x64 and JDK to 8 instead of latest or 9  :(

Answer (score 22):

The selected answer lead me in the right direction, but for Visual Studio 2017, the screen looks like:

[image: VS 2017 Updated Screens]

[image: VS 2017 Updated Screens]

Answer (score 18):

If you want to increase Heap size of your application (not the build process) you can set this in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:largeHeap="true"></application>
```

Answer (score 12):

For visual studio 2015 right click Project --> Properties --> Android Options --> Advanced and heap size there.

Comment: Make that: left-click <project>.Droid --> Double-click 'Properties' --> Click 'Android Options' on the left --> Click 'Advanced' tab --> "Java Max Heap Size"

Answer (score 7):

As of Xamarin studio version 6.3 and visual studio 7.0.1 the option to increase heap size can be found here

Right click on the android project then choose *options* and choose, *Build*/*Android Build*, then *Advanced* tab and set *1G* (or something) in *Java heap size*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

When you run out of 1G heap size, start to optimize resources.

First check if you are not duplicating images instances, keeping same image in memory several times. For that use ffimageloading library (https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) get it on nuget fast and easy.

Then optimize images you are using. For large images, other than icons, try converting everything to jpeg avoiding png with transparency, that once saved me for constant ooms.

Then try using thumbnails instead of images when you might have large uploaded images on remote. On your server pre-create thumbnails for different sizes, mini, small, medium, normal , large, xlarge etc, and load only images of size you really need. That saves a lot of memory and speed.

Another one is memory leaks. You might have cells or other elements still reside im memory if they didn't unsubscribe from messages, eventhandlers and some other. Imagine you could have several copies of a list full of images still in memory when you are sure that couldn't happen.  More info here:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/123876/should-we-unsubscribe-all-events-for-memory-management

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87206/messaging-center-unsubscribe-from-all-messages-when-broadcast-stops

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, memory issues ONLY happen on the android version of the Xamarin.Forms app. And it always have to deal with large-size images. I've dealt with this problem by using FFImageLoading(https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading)

Replace your

```
<Image Source="waterfront.jpg" />
```

With

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="waterfront.jpg"
DownsampleToViewSize = true,
BitmapOptimizations = true/>
```

You will see a drastic improvements in performance, and it will also solve your memory problems.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing java max heap size works for me

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had fixed adding   below  in application tag of AndroidManifiest.xml

```
<application  android:largeHeap="true" android:label="sample"></application>
```