# How to increase heap size in c# xamarin application?

Tags: xamarin.android, heap-memory

I develop an android application, in c#, using xamarin. It uses a lot of memory. For long time, I used weaker 2GB device to run it successfully. Now I changed phone for 4GB device and suddenly I get out of memory exception. It's caused by creating larger bitmaps.

**Here you can see output:**

```
(13022): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
(13022): Clamp target GC heap from 271MB to 256MB
(13022): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 255MB/256MB, paused 172us total 13.525ms
(13022): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 833KB allocation
(13022): Starting a blocking GC Alloc
(13022): Clamp target GC heap from 271MB to 256MB
(13022): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5(120B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 255MB/256MB, paused 175us total 13.474ms
(13022): Out of memory: Heap Size=256MB, Allocated=255MB, Capacity=256MB
```

I tried all possible combinations of setting `Java Max Heap Size = 1G` and writing to manifest `android:largeHeap="true"` as was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835790/getting-outofmemoryexception-in-xamarin) but it is still saying I'm only on 256MB, crashing at the same point. Any ideas why I don't get more heap memory? There is a lot of free memory in the system. When the time comes, I will do some optimizations, but at the moment I want to use full capabilities of my testing device to code easy way. I looked at various articles, questions and one of two highlighted actions always solved the problem. I have no idea what condition is wrong in my code.

**Edit:**

here is whole manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="AlienChessAndroid.AlienChessAndroid" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:largeHeap="true" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:label="Alien Chess" android:icon="@drawable/Alien">
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: It's wired if your app works fine on 2GB device but not on 4GB device, and `android:largeHeap="true"` doesn't work for your issue? Can you please show code of your manifest?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I edited the question with manifest file. I have quite some bitmaps I'm drawing into in my app and the display growed from HD to Quad HD, so this is the reason for more memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `android:largeHeap="true"` belongs to the `application` tag, please check the official document here: [application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap). You put this attribute in `manifest` tag, this should be the reason why `android:largeHeap="true"` doesn't work for your app.

By the way, maybe it's off topic, since your problem is caused by large bitmap,  using native memory (NDK & JNI) can actually bypass the heap size limitation. You can check this case: [JNI bitmap operations , for helping to avoid OOM when using large images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250951/jni-bitmap-operations-for-helping-to-avoid-oom-when-using-large-images).

Comment: That solved the problem. I think I will later remove all these large app-lifetime resources out from the heap, your link seems like great place where to start. Thank you!