# Xamarin bitmap out of memory

Tags: android, xamarin, bitmap, xamarin.forms

I have several pages with images. All images are either 
static:

```
<Image Source="logo.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="200" Aspect="AspectFit" />
```

or bound:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

I don't bind them through code.

After I move from one page to another several times, this exception appears

> Xamarin caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a
>   9437196 byte allocation with 5765944 free bytes and 5MB until OOM   at
>   dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)   at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)   at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:700)
>   at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:535)
>   at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:558) 
>   at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:588)

I tried calling GC.Collect() after page is closed, but doesn't work.

Comment: It seems your image file is too large and require more memory. Use a small image or increase memory size in config file. check following link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835790/getting-outofmemoryexception-in-xamarin

Comment: @PankajToshniwal , I already tried to increase memory size - didn't work. Also, all images are at most 800kb, I think this is not large image. I suppose there is a memory leak because OutOfMemory doesn't occur instantly, but after some time.

Comment: Need more of your page code to debug.

Comment: Try Adding <application android:label="MyApp" android:largeHeap="true"></application> in your manifest file

Comment: Use FFImageLoading library: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/tree/master/source

Comment: @ArtūrasPaleičikas, thank you. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

- try to increase your project heap size.

> Right click your Android Project > Properties > Android Options >
>   Advanced > Java Max Heap Size > set 1G

- try to call ***GC.Collect()*** before navigate to another page