# Xamarin Android Player - VBoxManage command failed

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-emulator, xamarin-android-player

I just installed Xamarin Android Player to test my Xamarin app. But I can't run emulator created in XAP.
[image: VBoxManage command failed.]

I read my log file but I don't know what wrong.
This is [my log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M3f0vDh-BcPcmGtPPRYpldyn-jM_trmI/view). Please help me.

Comment: Hi Fox, about the out of memory issue, have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36835891/2889347 that has helped me a lot in my personal case.

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete Thank you very much, after reading your comment, I reinstalled Genymotion and setting as you guided and it works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin Android Player is no more supported by xamarin, You can use

**Visual Studio Emulator for Android**
or  **Genymotion**

Comment: I tried all of them but I have some problem with them.  
+ **Genymotion**: Can't start emulator with API higher 19. With API 19, I always get OutOfMemory exception.  
+ **Visual Studio Emulator for Android**: I just can deploy my app to emulator and can't debug my code.

Comment: I can't fix Xamarin Android Player. I reinstalled Genymotion and now it looked good for me. Thank you.