# OutOfMemoryException when trying to import xml to android

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

i have xml file 230 mb big with 230 million length when i try to import the file to my android using an app that we made but when attempting `readtoend` string into variable im getting an error :

> System.outofmemoryexception : out of memory at (wrapper managed-to-native) system.string.fastallocatestring(int) at system.text.stringbuilder.tostring()

here's the following code

```
var documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString();
            var dirName = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath.ToString(), "Stock");

            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(dirName, "Data.xml");
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader(filePath);
            string result = tr.ReadToEnd();
            tr.Close();

            var st = new XStreamingElement(filePath);

            return result;
```

can anyone help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting OutOfMemoryException in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835790/getting-outofmemoryexception-in-xamarin)

Comment: Take a look at [What is the best way to parse (big) XML in C# Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/676274) and [Reading Xml with XmlReader in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2441673).

Answer (score 4):

Try using **XMLTextReader class** instead as the example below:

```
XmlTextReader myTextReader = new XmlTextReader(filename);
myTextReader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
while (myTextReader.Read())
{
    if (myTextReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
        myTextReader.LocalName == "Reward" &&
        myTextReader.IsStartElement() == true)
        {
            ProcessRewardNode(myTextReader);
                myTextReader.Skip();
    }
}
```

Here is the method implementation of **ProcessRewardNode**:

```
private void ProcessRewardNode(XmlTextReader RewardReader)
{
    XmlDocument RewardXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    RewardXmlDoc.LoadXml(RewardReader.ReadOuterXml());
    // we can use xpath as below
    myID = RewardXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("Reward/myID").InnerText;
}
```

for more info visit [XMLTextReader's official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextreader.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlTextReader__ctor_System_String_)